# Why do I get error while trying to build an architecture with multiple inputs in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build an architecture with multiple inputs in Keras. As mentioned in [1](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/), I used similar code as followed:

```
model_merged = Model(inputs=[model_parts1, model_parts2,
                             model_parts3, model_parts4])
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: _init_subclassed_network() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inputs'
```

I have searched online and some people mentioned that Keras should be updated to version 2.0.0; though I have version 2.2.2 installed which I suppose is not the problem.

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keras functional api Model expects two positional arguments namely `inputs`, and `outputs`.
The error

> TypeError: _init_subclassed_network() got an unexpected keyword
>   argument 'inputs'

is thrown when the output of the model is not specified.

```py
input1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(8,))
input2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(8,))
h1 = keras.layers.Concatenate()([input1, input2])
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2])
```

this throws the following error

```
TypeError: _init_subclassed_network() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inputs'
```

But if outputs are specified it works without error

```
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=h1)
```

Similar exception is thrown when the `outputs` argument is passed without `inputs` argument.

```py
model = keras.models.Model(outputs=h1)
```

```
TypeError: _init_subclassed_network() got an unexpected keyword argument 'outputs'
```

I think it would be very helpful, if the error message would have been more informative. The `inputs` and `outputs` arguments are "not unexpected" arguments here. It would be more informative if the error message would have been

```py
TypeError: _init_subclassed_network() missing expected keyword argument 'outputs'
```

for the former case where only `inputs` argument is specified and

```py
TypeError: _init_subclassed_network() missing expected keyword argument 'inputs'
```

for the later case where there only `outputs` argument is specified.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have both the inputs and the outputs defined and still I am getting this error. What could be the probable reason? The error is `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inputs'`.

Comment: @RishikMani Could you tell us more on how to reproduce your error?

Comment: @Mitiku thank you for the concern. Unfortunately, I defined a custom class with the name Model, which was interfering with keras.models.Model class. I have been able to resolve it. [This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617806/init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-inputs)